# FOP 2.3: Problems wiht fo:external-graphic

Tags: java, jar, apache-fop

This is my case when i execute my java jar application in server, not directly from IDE.

1. I have config files in this path: C:\Temp\myuser\myappname\config\xslt. The main archives are header.jpg, fopfile.xconf and style.stl
2. This applications calls to Zxing library to generate a qr code in order to attach to a PDF new file. My application runs in C:\Temp\myapp\myapp.jar, so the gneerated QRCode file in png format, will be saved in that path with name qrcode.png.
3. My xsl-fo file uses the infamous tag fo:external-graphic. For both cases I use:

`<fo:external-graphic src="url('file:\\C:\Temp\myuser\myappname\config\xslt\header.jpg')"/>`

`<fo:external-graphic src="url('file:\\C:\Temp\myapp\qrcode.png')"/>`

But again the jar crushes and says 
GRAVE: image not found, every time. I tried changing paths and the same error happens.

Now look, If i run this app from IDE -VSCode- this problem never happens.

Please guys help us what can we do? I read all the docs in the tutorial from apache but again nothing works.

note: I generate the jar via this: mvn clean compile assembly:single -f, so i create opne jar with all dependencies embedded in.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!--Just put this first dependency **xmlgraphics-commons** before the **fop** dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```